# Text Overlap Video tag CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm not sure as to why when I drag my browser around my text and video overlap. I want to prevent this:

Here is a jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/m3xug7vo/

example:

[image]

Here is the CSS regarding the particular page:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto; /* Centering blocks */
    /*position: relative;
    display: block;*/
}

.index {

}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    /*width: auto;
    height: auto;*/
    z-index: -100;
    background: no-repeat;
    /*background-size: cover;*/

    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.title-area {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
}


.index-aboutus {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.index-ourwork {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.index-instructors {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The HTML:

[image]

Comment: How to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @dfsq I added a jsfiddle on top that does reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The video container is using a height of 100vh, there is one thing you have to think of:

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However,
>   when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll
>   bars are assumed not to exist.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

An easy way to fix this would be to **add a class to the parent div of video-container and add a property to set it to overflow: hidden;**

It would look like the following:

```
.video-containerParent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please see the following jsFiddle for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/m3xug7vo/1/

The following site has an interesting article about viewport units:

https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/